# count days overlapping in array of dates to fixed date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of tasks with start and end dates associated and am then attempting to create a count of active task days each week over a number of weeks.

[excel screen shot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbJXa.jpg)

As I've attempted to show in the screen shot, using `=MAX(MIN(end1,end2)-MAX(start1,start2)+1,0)` I can get the overlap for one set of dates vs another and then sum across the week to get the answer for each week.

This solution is going to end up with a rather large matrix of calculations to get there though and I'm convinced there must be a more direct route.

I'm thinking array formulae? but struggling.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and try to explain your problem better please? I am a bit unsure of your problem without seeing more of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula in `G15`

`=SUM(TEXT(IF(C$3:C$6>F15+6,F15+6,C$3:C$6)-IF(B$3:B$6<F15,F15,B$3:B$6)+1,"0;\0")+0)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down

....or a non array version with `COUNTIFS` like this

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,"<="&F15+{0,1,2,3,4,5,6},C:C,">="&F15+{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}))`

In the first suggestion, because you can't easily use `MIN` and `MAX` in this type of formula the `IF`functions achieve the same thing. When the dates don't overlap this results in negative numbers so `TEXT` function is used to convert those to zeroes

In the `COUNTIFS` version each date in the week is tested to see if it falls in any of the date ranges.

I expect identical results for both formulas

Versions of both of these suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507712/finding-and-adding-together-overlaps-in-dates-from-2-different-columns-in-excel/47522569#47522569)

[image]